# What happens if I tell Software Updater : [y] Restart services during package upgrade without asking?

Tags: package-management, update-manager, workflow

Ubuntu Software Updater just offered me a checkbox while updating libssl1.1amd64:

Restart services during package upgrades without asking?

Is this permanent or per update session? And what are the risks of it putting a spanner in my works?

(The  button is, alas, not very informative.)

I can *guess* how this might be good and how it might potentially cause problems. Likewise, I can imagine times when it won't matter if it screws up my current workspaces + tasks, and times when I'm in the middle of something and can't risk the interruption.

So I can't really answer the question without first knowing **whether by checking the box I make the choice permanent**, and **what risks there are to my workflow and various open docs etc**. So does it, and what does it?

Comment: Related: [Does answering “no” on the “restart services during package upgrades without asking?” affect unattended-upgrades?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1152066/does-answering-no-on-the-restart-services-during-package-upgrades-without-ask)

Answer (score 2):

Two options. If the question is asked ...

1. in a GUI/desktop it will be permanent (there tends to be an "apply" button then). There are a few exceptions: when you start something that shows a graphical guide it could be 1 time (but the examples I can think of are the installer and gparted).
2. during a terminal action (ie. server, a tty login or a terminal prompt in a desktop) it will be 1 time only. For the option to be permanent you would need to alter a configuration file yourself.